# Display API Request/Response structure using swagger annotations for Java

Tags: java, annotations, swagger

I am new to swagger and am trying to add to the API docs, a sample input/output json for an API using swagger.io Annotations library. I tried something like this:

```
@other annotations here
public ResponseObj doSomething(@ApiParam(name = "testname", value = 
"test value", required = true, example = "{\"userId\":\"1234\"}" 
@RequestBody RequestObj req) {
    //some code here
}
```

In the output documentation I only see name, value and required fields and not the example. I even tried

```
examples = @Example(value = { @ExampleProperty(value = "examplepropvaluetest") }
```

but don't see that either.

Help anyone? TIA

Comment: Are you using spring-fox. With spring,  spring-fox swager integration works better

Comment: Yes, I am using spring-fox

Comment: if you are using springfox, then adding @RequestBody will be enough, it will be shown in the ui

Comment: I am using @RequestBody as shown in my question. It simply displays the schema(as in a table), but not the json format.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger displays any request / response as a model (tabular) and Example value (json).
See secreenshot below.

**As Model**

[image: Model]

**As Example Value (xml / json)**

[image: example]

Click on Model / Example Value to switch between them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using spring-restdocs(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs). Basically you generate the documents when you run the tests.